# How to remove non-ascii characters from strings in python

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

while working on a paragraph from a DB, I tried to use sent_tokenizer but kept getting some odd characters on a string that has an apostrophe as follows:
import re
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, tokenize

```
def foo():
    words = [location]
    corpus = ''.join(words) 
    sentences2 = sent_tokenize(corpus)

    print sentences1

foo()
```

with 'words' being a paragraph from the sqlite DB, I got this:

```
[u'The exact cause is unknown and is likely to involve multiple factors.', u'AAA formation and rupture may result from elastin and collagen degradation by proteases such as plasmin, matrix metalloproteinases (MMPs), and cathepsin S and K.\r\nInflammatory conditions such as arteritis.', u'Infective conditions such as syphilis and Salmonella bacterial infections.', u'The most common association with AAA is atherosclerosis.', u'Tobacco use accounts for >90% of people who develop an AAA have smoked at some point in their life.', u'There are high familial prevalence rates especially among the males.', u'The nature of the genetic disorder is unclear but may be linked to alpha-1-antitrypsin deficiency or X-linked mutation.', u'Connective tissue disorders, such as Marfan\u2019s syndrome and Ehlers-Danlos syndrome, have also been strongly associated with AAA.']
```

Instead of Marfan's, I get Marfan\u2019s

Using this code:

```
sentences1 = [x for x in corpus if x.isalnum()]
```

I get this:

```
[u'T', u'h', u'e', u'e', u'x', u'a', u'c', u't', u'c', u'a', u'u', u's', u'e', u'i', u's', u'u', u'n', u'k', u'n', u'o', u'w', u'n', u'a', u'n', u'd', u'i', u's', u'l', u'i', u'k', u'e', u'l', u'y', u't', u'o', u'i', u'n', u'v', u'o', u'l', u'v', u'e', u'm', u'u', u'l', u't', u'i', u'p', u'l', u'e', u'f', u'a', u'c', u't', u'o', u'r', u's', u'A', u'A', u'A', u'f', u'o', u'r', u'm', u'a', u't', u'i', u'o', u'n', u'a', u'n', u'd', u'r', u'u', u'p', u't', u'u', u'r', u'e', u'm', u'a', u'y', u'r', u'e', u's', u'u', u'l', u't', u'f', u'r', u'o', u'm', u'e', u'l', u'a', u's', u't', u'i', u'n', u'a', u'n', u'd', u'c', u'o', u'l', u'l', u'a', u'g', u'e', u'n', u'd', u'e', u'g', u'r', u'a', u'd', u'a', u't', u'i', u'o', u'n', u'b', u'y', u'p', u'r', u'o', u't', u'e', u'a', u's', u'e', u's', u's', u'u', u'c', u'h', u'a', u's', u'p', u'l', u'a', u's', u'm', u'i', u'n', u'm', u'a', u't', u'r', u'i', u'x', u'm', u'e', u't', u'a', u'l', u'l', u'o', u'p', u'r', u'o', u't', u'e', u'i', u'n', u'a', u's', u'e', u's', u'M', u'M', u'P', u's', u'a', u'n', u'd', u'c', u'a', u't', u'h', u'e', u'p', u's', u'i', u'n', u'S', u'a', u'n', u'd', u'K', u'I', u'n', u'f', u'l', u'a', u'm', u'm', u'a', u't', u'o', u'r', u'y', u'c', u'o', u'n', u'd', u'i', u't', u'i', u'o', u'n', u's', u's', u'u', u'c', u'h', u'a', u's', u'a', u'r', u't', u'e', u'r', u'i', u't', u'i', u's', u'I', u'n', u'f', u'e', u'c', u't', u'i', u'v', u'e', u'c', u'o', u'n', u'd', u'i', u't', u'i', u'o', u'n', u's', u's', u'u', u'c', u'h', u'a', u's', u's', u'y', u'p', u'h', u'i', u'l', u'i', u's', u'a', u'n', u'd', u'S', u'a', u'l', u'm', u'o', u'n', u'e', u'l', u'l', u'a', u'b', u'a', u'c', u't', u'e', u'r', u'i', u'a', u'l', u'i', u'n', u'f', u'e', u'c', u't', u'i', u'o', u'n', u's', u'T', u'h', u'e', u'm', u'o', u's', u't', u'c', u'o', u'm', u'm', u'o', u'n', u'a', u's', u's', u'o', u'c', u'i', u'a', u't', u'i', u'o', u'n', u'w', u'i', u't', u'h', u'A', u'A', u'A', u'i', u's', u'a', u't', u'h', u'e', u'r', u'o', u's', u'c', u'l', u'e', u'r', u'o', u's', u'i', u's', u'T', u'o', u'b', u'a', u'c', u'c', u'o', u'u', u's', u'e', u'a', u'c', u'c', u'o', u'u', u'n', u't', u's', u'f', u'o', u'r', u'9', u'0', u'o', u'f', u'p', u'e', u'o', u'p', u'l', u'e', u'w', u'h', u'o', u'd', u'e', u'v', u'e', u'l', u'o', u'p', u'a', u'n', u'A', u'A', u'A', u'h', u'a', u'v', u'e', u's', u'm', u'o', u'k', u'e', u'd', u'a', u't', u's', u'o', u'm', u'e', u'p', u'o', u'i', u'n', u't', u'i', u'n', u't', u'h', u'e', u'i', u'r', u'l', u'i', u'f', u'e', u'T', u'h', u'e', u'r', u'e', u'a', u'r', u'e', u'h', u'i', u'g', u'h', u'f', u'a', u'm', u'i', u'l', u'i', u'a', u'l', u'p', u'r', u'e', u'v', u'a', u'l', u'e', u'n', u'c', u'e', u'r', u'a', u't', u'e', u's', u'e', u's', u'p', u'e', u'c', u'i', u'a', u'l', u'l', u'y', u'a', u'm', u'o', u'n', u'g', u't', u'h', u'e', u'm', u'a', u'l', u'e', u's', u'T', u'h', u'e', u'n', u'a', u't', u'u', u'r', u'e', u'o', u'f', u't', u'h', u'e', u'g', u'e', u'n', u'e', u't', u'i', u'c', u'd', u'i', u's', u'o', u'r', u'd', u'e', u'r', u'i', u's', u'u', u'n', u'c', u'l', u'e', u'a', u'r', u'b', u'u', u't', u'm', u'a', u'y', u'b', u'e', u'l', u'i', u'n', u'k', u'e', u'd', u't', u'o', u'a', u'l', u'p', u'h', u'a', u'1', u'a', u'n', u't', u'i', u't', u'r', u'y', u'p', u's', u'i', u'n', u'd', u'e', u'f', u'i', u'c', u'i', u'e', u'n', u'c', u'y', u'o', u'r', u'X', u'l', u'i', u'n', u'k', u'e', u'd', u'm', u'u', u't', u'a', u't', u'i', u'o', u'n', u'C', u'o', u'n', u'n', u'e', u'c', u't', u'i', u'v', u'e', u't', u'i', u's', u's', u'u', u'e', u'd', u'i', u's', u'o', u'r', u'd', u'e', u'r', u's', u's', u'u', u'c', u'h', u'a', u's', u'M', u'a', u'r', u'f', u'a', u'n', u's', u's', u'y', u'n', u'd', u'r', u'o', u'm', u'e', u'a', u'n', u'd', u'E', u'h', u'l', u'e', u'r', u's', u'D', u'a', u'n', u'l', u'o', u's', u's', u'y', u'n', u'd', u'r', u'o', u'm', u'e', u'h', u'a', u'v', u'e', u'a', u'l', u's', u'o', u'b', u'e', u'e', u'n', u's', u't', u'r', u'o', u'n', u'g', u'l', u'y', u'a', u's', u's', u'o', u'c', u'i', u'a', u't', u'e', u'd', u'w', u'i', u't', u'h', u'A', u'A', u'A']
```

using this other code:

```
sentences1 = sent_tokenize(''.join(corpus.encode('utf8').decode('ascii','ignore')))
```

I get this:

```
[u'The exact cause is unknown and is likely to involve multiple factors.', u'AAA formation and rupture may result from elastin and collagen degradation by proteases such as plasmin, matrix metalloproteinases (MMPs), and cathepsin S and K.\r\nInflammatory conditions such as arteritis.', u'Infective conditions such as syphilis and Salmonella bacterial infections.', u'The most common association with AAA is atherosclerosis.', u'Tobacco use accounts for >90% of people who develop an AAA have smoked at some point in their life.', u'There are high familial prevalence rates especially among the males.', u'The nature of the genetic disorder is unclear but may be linked to alpha-1-antitrypsin deficiency or X-linked mutation.', u'Connective tissue disorders, such as Marfans syndrome and Ehlers-Danlos syndrome, have also been strongly associated with AAA.']
```

But Marfan's is converted to Marfans. Should stay as Marfan's

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found this to work well:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

corpus = "".join(words)
sent = []
sent.append(unidecode("".join(corpus)))
```